# How to send spinner id to server using JSON web services in android

Tags: android, json

Hello M using json parsing in my android application. M using php for web services.
M getting values in spinner from server. now i want to send back the particular spinner id back to the server how to send it please  help me.
Thnaks

My Code

```
class GetProviderName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{


    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd2=ProgressDialog.show(NewSales.this, "Loading", "Please wait");
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                view_rates = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(view_rates);





                JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(view_rates);
                System.out.println("Jarray Length:"+jarray.length());

        if(jarray.length()==0)
        {
            norecord=true;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jbnew=jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                int provider_id=Integer.valueOf(jbnew.getString("voucher_provider_id"));

                String voucher_provider_name=jbnew.getString("voucher_provider_name");
                Provider_structuer provider_dt=new Provider_structuer();
                provider_dt.setProvider_id(provider_id);
                provider_dt.setProvider_name(voucher_provider_name);
                all_provider_val.add(provider_dt);
                provider_names.add(voucher_provider_name);


                //jbnew.put("voucher_provider_id", provider_shop_names.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }
        }
        System.out.println("provider names" +provider_names.size());
        System.out.println("provider nshpos" +all_provider_val.size());



        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd2.dismiss();
        if(result)
        {
            ArrayAdapter<String>myadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewSales.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,provider_names);
            provider_shop_names.setAdapter(myadapter);
        }
        else
        {
            provider_shop_names.setAdapter(null);
            Toast.makeText(NewSales.this,"Sorry problem with connection.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If **provider_names** holds names and the **all_provider_val** corresponding values, you can use setOnItemSelectedListener on your spinner. You can get the position of the selected item. Then use that position to get the value from all_provider_val list. Something like that:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>myadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewSales.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,provider_names);
provider_shop_names.setAdapter(myadapter);

provider_shop_names.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id){
        String selectedValue = all_provider_val.get(position);
        //then return selectedValue to the web service
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your clicked spinner item id from `OnItemSelectedListener` event handler & send it back to server. For sending, you can use `HTTP POST`. Here is a code sample of sending data to server using HTTP POST:

```
// http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(orderJson));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            // response
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Order not submitted!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: "orderJson" is what I want to send to server. 

 `List<NameValuePair> orderJson= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

   orderJson.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order", json));
`
replace "json" with your spinner id.